# org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, dispatcher

As I run my spring application, I get 404 and the console is giving following warnings:

```
01-Aug-2016 15:38:27.799 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/drewnostal] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
01-Aug-2016 15:38:28.537 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/drewnostal] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

I have tried several solutions from different threads, none of them worked though.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="pl.drewnostal.controllers"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="jspViewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

IndexController.java:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showHome(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

index.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>$Title$</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  $END$
  </body>
</html>
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>pl.drewnostal</groupId>
<artifactId>drewnostal</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

[My project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJvhd.png)

Please help me ;)

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml also?

Comment: @VijendraKulhade edited

Comment: [318 and counting](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%22No+mapping+found+for+HTTP+request+with+URI%22+%22in+DispatcherServlet+with+name%22). Still no [spring] caretakers around here who's up for creating a canonical duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the project structure shared by you.
index.jsp is inside web/WEB-INF/views.
I created the same project as per standard maven war project and I put the index.jsp in webapp/WEB-INF/views and it worked for me.

Also In your project structure it seems web folder is outside source.
Usually we keep webapp inside source only.

If you will correct it. Your issue will be solved. Though I am not sure if you want to keep the structure like this only.

[image: Please follow this folder structure]

Comment: I moved the web folder into src, it's still not working though. Could you please either send me that project or try to launch mine?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByVUV9rtB8rzVjktZ1J1SWxZUWc/view

Comment: @Fryzjer I won't be able to run this in my machine. You have to rename the folder name web to webapp as per the maven standard and folder structure should be like I have updated in the answer.

Comment: It still doesn't work. Though the console doesn't display any warning now. My structure now looks like this: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByVUV9rtB8rzaUpQSi1lbzlGbnc

Comment: Structure looks fine now. Did you see any error in the logs? If everything loads fine You should see the controller mapping in the logs.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByVUV9rtB8rzUEMyLXE0VjFsU0k
This is what i get in logs. Tomcat Locathost Log and Tomcat Catalina Log are clear.

Comment: @Fryzjer Everything looks fine now You should see the index page. Please check once more if you are missing anything. I saw $END$ in the page.

Comment: Actually I have added <mvc:default-servlet-handler/> to servlet by a mistake (that was one of my attempts to solve the problem), and that's why warning disappeared. After removing this line, warning and error still occur.